# How to work with .raw format files for hyperspectral images analysis

Tags: image-processing

I am working on a hyperspectral image classification project on diseased oranges, where I need to classify if the oranges are diseased or not. The data is in .raw format and the problem is no language or framework seems to support that format when I try to convert the file to .mat file the image get corrupted or something happened.
I am really drowning and can use any help.

Comment: `.raw` is not a well-specified format. You'll need to state where it came from, what device produced it and share everything you know about its width, height, number of spectral channels, sample size/type, and whether planar or packed and also share a sample using Google Drive, or Dropbox, Github or similar.